# DataTable JS Unable to Filter on Column With Decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, filtering

I want to enable filtering on a DataTable column that has numbers with decimals. I am able to have the code successfully run on a table without decimals, but it cannot sort with decimal numbers. Any way to modify the below to accommodate decimals?

```
/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
                var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
                var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
                var age = parseFloat( data[1] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

                if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
                     ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
                     ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
                     ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        );

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();

            // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
            $('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
                table.draw();
            });
        });
```

I am wondering if changing the parseInt from the min and max variables to parseFloat will work, but then I am not sure if I need to modify isNaN?

Comment: I would try a `parseFloat()` on a value that had the coma replaced by a dot: `parseFloat( data[1].replace(",",".") ) || 0;`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Can you explain that a bit? My table doesn't have commas it only has decimals. Are you saying parseInt interpenetrates the decimals in my table as a comma? My understanding was the issue is parseInt since numbers with decimals are false.

Comment: Ho... Sorry, I think I hallucinated a coma issue...

Comment: So parseFloat should do... Why the base 25 (second argument of parseInt) ? Usually, decimals are base 10...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Oh! That should indeed be 10.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I am going to try this with the 25 changed to a 10 and the parseInt on the min and max changed to parseFloat. I don't think this is the most streamlined, but getting it working with decimals will be the first step.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt on the min and max variables should be changed to parseFloat to enable filtering on decimal values, since parseInt returns numbers with decimals as NaN.

Answer (score 0):

For that column you can use Datatables filter attribute

> "data-filter"

```
<td data-filter="62,5">62.5</td>
```

and then in search column replace deciman "." with ","

```
if(colIdx == 5){
       var searchval = this.value.replace(".",",");
}else{
      var searchval = this.value;
}
```

colIdx is column id because i used custom search fileds

you can directly use `var searchval = this.value.replace(".",",");`